# Why scala throws exception after command sbt run?

Tags: scala, sbt

Don't understand why this throws exceptions after command `sbt run`

I tried `sbt clean` and `sbt update` before

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ApplicationException: Error parsing: /api/details]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon
fun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:166) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anon
fun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply
(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply
(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: core.exceptions.ApplicationException: Error parsing: /api/details
        at rest.Details$$anonfun$request$1.apply(Details.scala:62) ~[na:na]
        at rest.Details$$anonfun$request$1.apply(Details.scala:60) ~[na:na]
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:236) ~[scala-librar
y-2.11.5.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) ~[scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:236) ~[scala-library-2.11.5.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give more details about the context of your issue but it looks like there is something wrong in your **config/routes** file.

You will find some documentation about Playframework routing here : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting